# Android - Keep VideoView playing after pressing HOME or BACK button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-videoview

In Android development, is it possible to keep a VideoView playing after sending the user to HOME screen, so, when the user opens the Application once again, the video is already running?

Like, when I leave the activity, the video stops playing and when I go back to the same Activity, the video restarts. Is there some way to keep it running, like in the background?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your `onPause()` of the activity you can pause the video get the current seekLevel by `getCurrentPosition()` and in your on resume if the video was playting you can pick up where you left of